# WebRTC Android Library function not getting called

Tags: android, webrtc

I am using the following open-source webrtc android application:

https://github.com/pchab/AndroidRTC

I have just modified this application to use my socket.io server instead of using the following one which is given by same author:

https://github.com/pchab/ProjectRTC

To do this, I needed to do some changes in the two classes of the above AndroidRTC Application. After this, when I started the application it did not call the 'createOffer()' or 'createAnswer()' function which is part of libjingle_peerconnection library. I am confused whether these two functions are not getting called or they are not able to use 'sendMessage()' function.

From debugging, I came to know that line which calls 'createAnswer()' function is successfully reached. After this, I expect the 'createAnswer()' function to use my 'sendMessage()' function to send the answer back to other party by using my socket.io server. I am not able to peek inside this 'createAnswer()' function as it is part of the library.

Before changing the above application to use my own server, I had tested it with the server given by auhtor. It ran successfully. I don't know what is wrong when I use my own server to make calls and do handshaking. I just modified few lines to support the way I do signalling on the server.

My server code is already used for webrtc web application. Web Applications are successful in making calls using this server. It should work for this android application too with little modification on the application.

I modified the following two classes in android application:

**RTCActivity.java**

```
package fr.pchab.AndroidRTC;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.Toast;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
import org.webrtc.VideoRenderer;

import java.util.List;

public class RTCActivity extends Activity implements WebRtcClient.RTCListener{

  private final static int VIDEO_CALL_SENT = 666;
  private VideoStreamsView vsv;
  private WebRtcClient client;
  private String mSocketAddress;
  private String callerId;


  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {


    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);


    mSocketAddress = "https://" + getResources().getString(R.string.host);
    mSocketAddress += (":"+getResources().getString(R.string.port)+"/");

    PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals(this);

    // Camera display view
    Point displaySize = new Point();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getSize(displaySize);
    vsv = new VideoStreamsView(this, displaySize);


    client = new WebRtcClient(this, mSocketAddress);

    final Intent intent = getIntent();
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action)) {
      final List<String> segments = intent.getData().getPathSegments();
      callerId = segments.get(0);
    }
  }

  public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig)
  {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    vsv.onPause();
  }

  @Override
  public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    vsv.onResume();
  }

  @Override
  public void onCallReady(String callId) {
      startCam();
  }

  public void answer(String callerId) throws JSONException {
    client.sendMessage(callerId, "init", null);
    startCam();
  }


  public void call(String callId) {
    Intent msg = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    msg.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, mSocketAddress + callId);
    msg.setType("text/plain");
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(msg, "Call someone :"), VIDEO_CALL_SENT);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == VIDEO_CALL_SENT) {
      startCam();
    }
  }

  public void startCam() {
    setContentView(vsv);
    // Camera settings
    client.setCamera("front", "640", "480");
    client.start("android_test", true);
  }

  @Override
  public void onStatusChanged(final String newStatus) {
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), newStatus, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    });
  }

  @Override
  public void onLocalStream(MediaStream localStream) {
    localStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallbacks(vsv, 0)));
  }

  @Override
  public void onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint) {
    remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).addRenderer(new VideoRenderer(new VideoCallbacks(vsv, endPoint)));
    vsv.shouldDraw[endPoint] = true;
  }

  @Override
  public void onRemoveRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint) {
    remoteStream.videoTracks.get(0).dispose();
    vsv.shouldDraw[endPoint] = false;
  }

  // Implementation detail: bridge the VideoRenderer.Callbacks interface to the
  // VideoStreamsView implementation.
  private class VideoCallbacks implements VideoRenderer.Callbacks {
    private final VideoStreamsView view;
    private final int stream;

    public VideoCallbacks(VideoStreamsView view, int stream) {
      this.view = view;
      this.stream = stream;
    }

    @Override
    public void setSize(final int width, final int height) {
      view.queueEvent(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
          view.setSize(stream, width, height);
        }
      });
    }

    @Override
    public void renderFrame(VideoRenderer.I420Frame frame) {
      view.queueFrame(stream, frame);
    }
  }
}
```

**WebRTCClient.java**

```
package fr.pchab.AndroidRTC;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedList;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import org.webrtc.DataChannel;
import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
import org.webrtc.MediaConstraints;
import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
import org.webrtc.PeerConnectionFactory;
import org.webrtc.SdpObserver;
import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;
import org.webrtc.VideoCapturer;
import org.webrtc.VideoSource;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.Acknowledge;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.ConnectCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.EventCallback;
import com.koushikdutta.async.http.socketio.SocketIOClient;

class WebRtcClient {

  private final static int MAX_PEER = 2;
  private boolean[] endPoints = new boolean[MAX_PEER];
  private PeerConnectionFactory factory;
  private HashMap<String, Peer> peers = new HashMap<String, Peer>();
  private LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer> iceServers = new LinkedList<PeerConnection.IceServer>();
  private MediaConstraints pcConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
  private MediaStream lMS;
  private RTCListener mListener;
  private SocketIOClient client;
  private final MessageHandler messageHandler = new MessageHandler();
  private final static String TAG = WebRtcClient.class.getCanonicalName();

  public interface RTCListener{
    void onCallReady(String callId);

    void onStatusChanged(String newStatus);

    void onLocalStream(MediaStream localStream);

    void onAddRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint);

    void onRemoveRemoteStream(MediaStream remoteStream, int endPoint);
  }

  private interface Command{
    void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException;
  }

  private class CreateOfferCommand implements Command{
    public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG,"CreateOfferCommand");
      Peer peer = peers.get(peerId);
      peer.pc.createOffer(peer, pcConstraints);
    }
  }

  private class CreateAnswerCommand implements Command{
    public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG,"CreateAnswerCommand");
      Peer peer = peers.get(peerId);
      SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
                                                      SessionDescription.Type.fromCanonicalForm(payload.getString("type")),
                                                      payload.getString("sdp")
                                                      );
      peer.pc.setRemoteDescription(peer, sdp);
      peer.pc.createAnswer(peer, pcConstraints);
    }
  }

  private class SetRemoteSDPCommand implements Command{
    public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG,"SetRemoteSDPCommand");
      Peer peer = peers.get(peerId);
      SessionDescription sdp = new SessionDescription(
                                                      SessionDescription.Type.fromCanonicalForm(payload.getString("type")),
                                                      payload.getString("sdp")
                                                      );
      peer.pc.setRemoteDescription(peer, sdp);
    }
  }

  private class AddIceCandidateCommand implements Command{
    public void execute(String peerId, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
        Log.d(TAG,"AddIceCandidateCommand");
      PeerConnection pc = peers.get(peerId).pc;
      if (pc.getRemoteDescription() != null) {
        IceCandidate candidate = new IceCandidate(
                                                  payload.getString("id"),
                                                  payload.getInt("label"),
                                                  payload.getString("candidate")
                                                  );
        pc.addIceCandidate(candidate);
      }
    }
  }

  public void sendMessage(String to, String type, JSONObject payload) throws JSONException {
    JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
    //message.put("room", to);
    message.put("type", type);
    message.put("msg", payload);
    message.put("room", "sojharo");
    client.emit("message", new JSONArray().put(message));
  }

  private class MessageHandler implements EventCallback {
    private HashMap<String, Command> commandMap;

    public MessageHandler() {
      this.commandMap = new HashMap<String, Command>();
      commandMap.put("init", new CreateOfferCommand());
      commandMap.put("offer", new CreateAnswerCommand());
      commandMap.put("answer", new SetRemoteSDPCommand());
      commandMap.put("candidate", new AddIceCandidateCommand());
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(String s, JSONArray jsonArray, Acknowledge acknowledge) {
      try {
          Log.d(TAG,"MessageHandler.onEvent() "+ (s == null ? "nil" : s));
        if(s.equals("id")) {

            JSONObject message = new JSONObject();

            message.put("room", "sojharo");
            message.put("username", "android");

            client.emit("create or join livehelp",
                    new JSONArray().put(message));

        } else if (s.equals("joined")) {
            mListener.onCallReady("Not Initiator");
        } else {

          JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);


          try{
                if(json.getString("msg").equals("got user media"))
                    return ;
            }catch(JSONException e){}

            String from = json.getString("from");
            String type = null;
            try{
                type = json.getString("type");
            }catch(JSONException e){}


          // if peer is unknown, try to add him
          if(!peers.containsKey(from)) {
            // if MAX_PEER is reach, ignore the call
            int endPoint = findEndPoint();
            if(endPoint != MAX_PEER) {
              addPeer(from, endPoint);

              commandMap.get(type).execute(from, json);
            }
          } else {
            commandMap.get(type).execute(from, json);
          }
        }
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private class Peer implements SdpObserver, PeerConnection.Observer{
    private PeerConnection pc;
    private String id;
    private int endPoint;

    @Override
    public void onCreateSuccess(final SessionDescription sdp) {
      try {
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        payload.put("type", sdp.type.canonicalForm());
        payload.put("sdp", sdp.description);
        sendMessage(id, sdp.type.canonicalForm(), payload);
        pc.setLocalDescription(Peer.this, sdp);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSetSuccess() {}

    @Override
    public void onCreateFailure(String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onSetFailure(String s) {}

    @Override
    public void onSignalingChange(PeerConnection.SignalingState signalingState) {}

    @Override
    public void onIceConnectionChange(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState iceConnectionState) {
      if(iceConnectionState == PeerConnection.IceConnectionState.DISCONNECTED) {
        removePeer(id);
        mListener.onStatusChanged("DISCONNECTED");
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onIceGatheringChange(PeerConnection.IceGatheringState iceGatheringState) {}

    @Override
    public void onIceCandidate(final IceCandidate candidate) {
      try {
        JSONObject payload = new JSONObject();
        payload.put("label", candidate.sdpMLineIndex);
        payload.put("id", candidate.sdpMid);
        payload.put("candidate", candidate.sdp);
        sendMessage(id, "candidate", payload);
      } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {}

    @Override
    public void onAddStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
        Log.d(TAG,"onAddStream "+mediaStream.label());

      // remote streams are displayed from 1 to MAX_PEER (0 is localStream)
      mListener.onAddRemoteStream(mediaStream, endPoint+1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRemoveStream(MediaStream mediaStream) {
      mListener.onRemoveRemoteStream(mediaStream, endPoint);

      removePeer(id);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel) {}

    public Peer(String id, int endPoint) {
        Log.d(TAG,"new Peer: "+id + " " + endPoint);
      this.pc = factory.createPeerConnection(iceServers, pcConstraints, this);
      this.id = id;
      this.endPoint = endPoint;

      pc.addStream(lMS, new MediaConstraints());

      mListener.onStatusChanged("CONNECTING");
    }
  }

  public WebRtcClient(RTCListener listener, String host) {
    mListener = listener;
    factory = new PeerConnectionFactory();

    SocketIOClient.connect(host, new ConnectCallback() {

      @Override
      public void onConnectCompleted(Exception ex, SocketIOClient socket) {
        if (ex != null) {
            Log.e(TAG,"WebRtcClient connect failed: "+ex.getMessage());
          return;
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"WebRtcClient connected.");
        client = socket;

        // specify which events you are interested in receiving
        client.addListener("id", messageHandler);
        client.addListener("message", messageHandler);
        client.addListener("joined", messageHandler);
      }
    }, new Handler());

    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:23.21.150.121"));
    iceServers.add(new PeerConnection.IceServer("stun:stun.l.google.com:19302"));

    pcConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveAudio", "true"));
    pcConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("OfferToReceiveVideo", "true"));
  }

  public void setCamera(String cameraFacing, String height, String width){
    MediaConstraints videoConstraints = new MediaConstraints();
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxHeight", height));
    videoConstraints.mandatory.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("maxWidth", width));

    VideoSource videoSource = factory.createVideoSource(getVideoCapturer(cameraFacing), videoConstraints);
    lMS = factory.createLocalMediaStream("ARDAMS");
    lMS.addTrack(factory.createVideoTrack("ARDAMSv0", videoSource));
    lMS.addTrack(factory.createAudioTrack("ARDAMSa0"));

    mListener.onLocalStream(lMS);
  }

  private int findEndPoint() {
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_PEER; i++) {
      if(!endPoints[i]) return i;
    }
    return MAX_PEER;
  }

  public void start(String name, boolean privacy){
    try {
        JSONObject message = new JSONObject();
        message.put("msg", new JSONObject().put("msg", "got user media"));
        message.put("room", "sojharo");
        client.emit("message", new JSONArray().put(message));
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  /*
   Cycle through likely device names for the camera and return the first
   capturer that works, or crash if none do.
   */
  private VideoCapturer getVideoCapturer(String cameraFacing) {
    int[] cameraIndex = { 0, 1 };
    int[] cameraOrientation = { 0, 90, 180, 270 };
    for (int index : cameraIndex) {
      for (int orientation : cameraOrientation) {
        String name = "Camera " + index + ", Facing " + cameraFacing +
        ", Orientation " + orientation;
        VideoCapturer capturer = VideoCapturer.create(name);
        if (capturer != null) {
          return capturer;
        }
      }
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Failed to open capturer");
  }

  private void addPeer(String id, int endPoint) {
    Peer peer = new Peer(id, endPoint);
    peers.put(id, peer);

    endPoints[endPoint] = true;
  }

  private void removePeer(String id) {
    Peer peer = peers.get(id);
    peer.pc.close();
    peer.pc.dispose();
    peers.remove(peer.id);

    endPoints[peer.endPoint] = false;
  }
}
```

The code is able to receive the offer and candidates from other party. It is not able to send the answer or candidates to that party in return.

I have not modified other two classes which can be found on the above link for android application.

Here is snippet of my socket.io server code written in nodejs:

```
    socket.on('create or join livehelp', function (room) {
        var numClients = socketio.sockets.clients(room.room).length;

        if (numClients === 0){
            socket.join(room.room);
            socket.set('nickname', room.username);    
            socket.emit('created', room);
        } else if (numClients < 2) {
            socket.join(room.room);
            socket.set('nickname', room.username);    
            socket.emit('joined', room);

            socket.broadcast.to(room.room).emit('join', room);

        } else { // max three clients
            socket.emit('full', room.room);
        }

        console.log(socketio.sockets.manager.rooms)
        console.log(room)

    });


    socket.on('message', function (message) {
        //console.log('Got message:', message);

        //socket.broadcast.emit('message', message);

        message.msg.from = socket.id;

        //socketio.sockets.in(message.room).emit('message', message.msg);
        socket.broadcast.to(message.room).emit('message', message.msg);
        //console.log('Got message:', message.msg);
        //console.log(socketio.sockets.manager.rooms)

    });
```

I am confused if there is any error why I am not able to find it in debugging. Log for this is very difficult to read as it runs very fast and I am not able to catch each and every line. But apparently, it looked fine at a glance.

Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not able to generate answer but you are able to generate offer?. If this is the case try adding

```
pcConstraints.optional.add(new MediaConstraints.KeyValuePair("DtlsSrtpKeyAgreement", "true"));
```

to your pc constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help..
 client.on('message', function (details) {
          console.log('message',details.to);

```
       console.log(details.type);
       if(details.type !== 'init'){

            var otherClient = io.sockets.connected[details.to];

            if (!otherClient) {
              return;
            }

              delete details.to;
              details.from = client.id;
              otherClient.emit('message', details);

        }
        else
        {

            if (io.sockets.adapter.rooms[client.room] !== undefined ) {

                for(var member in io.sockets.adapter.rooms[client.room]){
                    console.log(member);
                    if(member !== client.id){
                        var otherClient = io.sockets.connected[member];

                        if (!otherClient) {
                          return;
                        }
                          delete details.to;
                          details.from = client.id;
                          otherClient.emit('message', details);
                      }
                      else{
                          console.log("no need to send self again!");
                      }
                }
            } else {
                    client.emit("update", "Please connect to a room.");
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Please download latest libjingle from here

http://repo.spring.io/libs-release-remote/io/pristine/libjingle/